# My VueJS app is not rendering - I have looked at other solutions on stack overflow but none of them seem to solve my problem

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have a simple Vue.Js App I need to render but the app is not being rendered at all.

I followed all the examples shown online and everything looks correct but I can't spot the problem. I am using Vue.js on an ASP.net application with webpack

My Index.cshtml:

```
@section scripts{
    <environment names="Development,Production,Staging">
        <script src="~/dist/js/home/bundle.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
}
<div id="app">
</div>
```

My main app.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.config.performance = true;

Vue.use(VueRouter);

import store from './store/store';
import { router } from './router/router';

import App from './App.vue';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

My App.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="column is-3">
                    <section class="section">
                        <aside class="menu">
                            <p class="menu-label">
                                Examples
                            </p>
                            <ul class="menu-list">
                                <li>
                                    <router-link :to="{ name: 'counter' }">Counter</router-link>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <p class="menu-label">
                                About
                            </p>
                            <ul class="menu-list">
                                <li>
                                    <router-link :to="{ name: 'moduleinfo' }">Module info</router-link>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </aside>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-9">

                    <section class="section">
                        <transition name="component-fade"
                                    mode="out-in">
                            <router-view></router-view>
                        </transition>
                    </section>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <notifications group="global" />
    </div>

</template>
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import Notifications from 'vue-notification'

Vue.use(Notifications)

export default {
  name: 'App'
    }
</script>
<style scoped>

</style>
```

There are no errors being thrown, the app simply doesnt render and the only html on the page when i run the application is

```
<div id=app>
</div>
```

Comment: have you looked to see if you have anything in your bundle.js?

Comment: @KeithNicholas Yes the bundle.js exists and has content, I have also checked that it has the right content, when i change the App.vue file it recreated bundle.js with the right content